# How to receive error in jQuery AJAX response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery $.ajax() function to perform a database insert operation on a php page. So, on success it will do the regular operation but I want the ajax call to receive error if the update operation fails.

So it should be:

1. $.ajax -> call php function
2. Receive success on successful record insert
3. Receive error on unsuccessfull insert

So, should I do a return false; from my php function? I think the $.ajax() success or error depends if the AJAX call was successful or not. So, I think even if I return false; from my php function it will still be considered a "success" for the ajax call. Right

Answer (score 3):

You could return the error message in your server response (or using JSON) as someone suggested. But I don't like it too much because this pollutes the data returned.

I like another way I've been using recently, which involves creating a custom HTTP header to inform if there was an error.

PHP code:

```
if($there_was_error){
   header("DB_SUCCESS: 0"); //Sends a custom header
}else{
   header("DB_SUCCESS: 1");
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data, status, xhr){
     //You can use your 'data' var as always
     if(xhr.getResponseHeader("DB_SUCCESS") == 1){
        alert("Save successful");
        //Your regular sutff
     }else{
        alert("Save failed");
     }         
  }
  ...
})
```

As you can see, we created a custom HTTP header, called `DB_SUCCESS` to be used as metadata, so we can assign it server-side  (php) and read it with client-side (javascript) to know if there was an error.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: I think that you got confused with the if statement.. The 1 should go in the else case (no error was found) and the 0 should go in the if there_was_error case. :)

Comment: Why a custom error header instead of a standard HTTP error code?

Comment: @Mike, I want to show to BlueBoy that he can use custom headers, for example he could put the database error message in a header. In this example it's boolean but it can be whatever.

Comment: Is there any way that I can customize a PHP return so that AJAX picks it up in its ERROR handler instead of its SUCCESS one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle PHP's success/error inside your $.ajax() success: function

Assume this is your ajax.php:

```
if($whatever)
{
  echo 'success';
}
else
{
  echo 'fail';
}
```

Assume this is your javascript $.ajax():

```
success: function(data)
{
    switch(data)
    {
        case 'success':
            // handle good logic
            break;
        case 'fail':
        default:
            // handle bad logic
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I evaluate response from the server and if error occurred in the PHP, it simply outputs JavaScript code to show error.

Works well with all sorts of things including re-login on session-timeouts, access restrictions, exception handling and everything else.

I wish this approach would be more popular.

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/templates/js/atk4_univ.js#L413

Answer (score 1):

This is simple, in short: you can catch any thing returned from PHP.

IN DETAIL: the below code snippet may help you clearly understand the issue.

PHP

```
$result = //your database result
if($result){
    //Print any success message you want the user to see   
    echo "Success";
}else{
    //Print any error message you want the user to see   
    echo "Error";
}
```

JQUERY

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controller.php",
    data: params,
    success: function(msg){

    //Alert the returned message to the user,
    //the variable msg already contains your message 
    //whether it is success or error,
    //it can even contain HTML or JavaScript
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build up an array in PHP. Such as

```
$status['completed'] = true;
$status['message'] = "Completed";
```

Depends on how you go with insert change those two values.

Then I would do http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php `json_encode` and echo it out. Your jQuery would receive `JSON` and if the `completed` is **true** then its all fine. If **false**, check the `message`.

You could also use `getJSON` method from jQuery to make it even easier.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is happening on the client.

Your PHP is over on the server.

Here's an *excellent* example that might help:

[jQuery AJAX error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031168/jquery-ajax-error-handling)

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: "action=login&user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass,
        success: function(xhr){
            if ((xhr == "Invalid Login") 
                    || (xhr == "Invalid charaters in username.") 
                    || (xhr == "Missing username or password.")
                    || (xhr == "Unknown Error")) {
                $("#loginMessageContent").html(xhr);
            }
            else {
                simplemodalClose (dialog);
            }
       }, 
       error: function(xhr) {
           alert ("Oopsie: " + xhr.statusText);
       }
    });
```

Comment: In this case, an error should be returned by PHP as an actual HTTP error code, such as 404 or 500.

Comment: Hey, guys.  Did you even LOOK at the excerpt this was quoted from???  "xhr" is simply an (admittedly poorly named) variable.  You guys are hair-trigger with your responses, and merciless with your comments.