# Jquery .post not working on one function, working on another

Tags: jquery

I have two functions to submit to different sets of data to the same page. One function works fine, but the other doesn't send the post data. Here is the code:

```
    function sortManufacturer() {
        showLoading();
        var orderList = '';
        orderedNodes = document.getElementById("sortable_list").getElementsByTagName("li");
            for (var i=0;i < orderedNodes.length;i++) {
                orderList += orderedNodes[i].getAttribute('recordid') + ',';
            }
$.post( 'save_sort_order.php', {type:'manufacturer', order: orderList},
        function() {
        hideLoading();
        $( ".saved" ).dialog( "open" );
        }
);}
    function editManufacturer() {
        showLoading();
        var fields = $("form#edit_manufacturer").serializeArray();
$.post( 'save_sort_order.php', {manActive: fields},
        function(data) {
        hideLoading();
        $( ".saved" ).dialog( "open" );
        }
);}
```

This doesn't work either, no alert saying success and no alert throwing an error. Just reloads the page.:

```
    function editManufacturer() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save_sort_order.php",
    data: "hey",
    success: function(){
        alert("success");
   }, 
   error: function(request, status, error) {
       var result = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        alert(result.message);
   }
});
    }
```

No post data is being sent in Firebug under the Net panel. The first function works fine, the second is the one not being sent. If I put alert("after"); after the $.post right before the closing } of the function, it works fine.

Comment: Which function doesn't work and which does?

Comment: Have you checked firebug to see if the request is sent?  Do you mean it's never getting sent or you are not getting a response?  Using firebug, put console.log("some identifier") between troubling lines to find out what does get executed and what doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? What are you expecting and what are the results you're getting ?

Comment: The first function works fine, the second doesn't run anything in the .post function. Even if I just add an alert with the text "hey" in it to the function() part of the post it doesn't show it.

Comment: @PiontekMedia that would be because your server side script threw an error and AJAX success handler is not being called. Wrapping content of the handler in a try/catch would make it visible to you.

Comment: A success handler is being called, it's function(). Same exact one I use on the first function and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by adding an `error handler` to `$.post`, see the message it returns.
Also look at `firebug net panel` to see the request and response

http://getfirebug.com/network

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel

*edit*

refer thread:-
[jQuery AJAX error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031168/jquery-ajax-error-handling)

change your ajax syntax for how its give over there. its more readable that way.

also replace error handler with

```
error: function(request, status, error) {
        var result = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        alert(result.message);
    });
```

Comment: It doesn't show any request under the net panel for POST, so it's not even sending it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried what you said, but no alert pops up, neither the success one, or one with an error. I've updated the original post with the new function for you to take a look at.

Comment: you said it `Just reloads the page`.why is that happening? 2nd, you also said the net panel isnt showing your request. check if your code is making ajax call. net panel shows failed requests as well.

Comment: Checked net panel again, now it is showing the right values under post parameters, but nothing is being returned. Still no alert for success or failure. The data isn't being sent to the PHP file either.

Comment: just to make sure.. you can see `manActive` being sent to php and net panel not showing any error in `response` tab for this request? also your php code is not being hit as well.. correct?

Answer (score 0):

The `serializeArray()` return array of name/value pairs, which you additionally wrapping into `manActive` field. Just pass `fields` as is and it should work.

EDIT: I also support the question to the OP. While it was possible for me to notice the issue, you should always put some debug effort into it first. Such as examining your post data in Firebug or Fiddler. The "doesn't work" is really not a description of a problem.

Comment: That's not the issue, I've put hours of debugging into it. If I add an alert(""); right after the $.POST and right before the closing bracket of the function, it works fine. Except there is a blank alert on the screen. All data is submitted and returned though, as long as I have an alert after $.POST

Answer (score 0):

I would set up alerts on the objects at each line. It's a bit tedious but usually works. If you are using an object which might be null or of the wrong datatype and jQuery expects it otherwise, it'll fail silently. Make sure the getElementsById works, that the orderList is as expected, etc. It could also be failing in the php.