# Return the result of form submission from PHP to JavaScript, differentiating between success and failure

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

jQuery:

```
$("#register-form").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    $.post("./register.php", {
        username: $("#username").val(), 
        password: $("#password").val(),
        passwordtwo: $("#passwordtwo").val(),
        email: $("#email").val()
    },
    function(response) {
        $("#errors").html(response);
        $("#errors").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

This works perfectly and displays the errors I return. But if the form passes all the checks I get a problem.

```
if ($error) {
    echo $error; // returns errors in form
} else {
    // Password Hash & Salt functions are here
    // sets a cookie to log them in here
        header("Location: " . getenv("HTTP_REFERER")); // the problem
}
```

Because of my current jQuery function, the response will return the `HTTP_REFERER` so it loads the who previous page inside the `<div id="errors"></div>` I have.

Is there some kind of success parameter or some way to do something else if it passes all the checks?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031168/jquery-ajax-error-handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **JSON** on PHP part,

```
    if ($error) {
        echo '{"error":"$error", "success":false}'; // returns errors in form
    } else {
        // Password Hash & Salt functions are here
        // sets a cookie to log them in here

        echo '{"error":"", "success":true}';
    }
```

And modify *Javascript* to handle the json.

```
$("#register-form").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    $.post("./register.php", {
        username: $("#username").val(), 
        password: $("#password").val(),
        passwordtwo: $("#passwordtwo").val(),
        email: $("#email").val()
    },
    function(response) {
        if(!response.success) { alert("error:" + response.error);}
            else { window.location.reload(); }
    },
    'json' 
    ); // add json type
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But is it supposed to output `'{"error":"$error", "success":false}'` as a string?

Comment: @Aaron Yes. An example output would be `{"error":"username password pair doesn't match", "success": false}`

Answer (score 2):

If you make ajax request, then you have to redirect within javascript. So you can do

```
$("#register-form").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    $.post("./register.php", {
        username: $("#username").val(), 
        password: $("#password").val(),
        passwordtwo: $("#passwordtwo").val(),
        email: $("#email").val()
    },
    function(response) {
        if ( response = '' ) { window.location.reload(); }
        else {
            $("#errors").html(response);
            $("#errors").slideDown("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

and echo nothing out in there are no errors
    if ($error) { echo $error; }

Better way is to use JSON instead. On error return `{ error: 'Error message' }` and else `{ success: true }`

Then on javascript side you check is response.error is present

More info: http://www.json.org/

Comment: There is no `refresh()` method in `location` object. Its `reload()`.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code suggested by Shiplu is perfect. Use datatype:json in the ajax call.

```
$("#register-form").submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault();
    $.post("./register.php", {
        username: $("#username").val(), 
        password: $("#password").val(),
        passwordtwo: $("#passwordtwo").val(),
        email: $("#email").val()
    },
    function(response) {
        if ( response.success.toString() = 'true' ) { window.location.reload(); }
        else {
            $("#errors").html(response.error);
            $("#errors").slideDown("slow");
        }
    }, "json"); });
```